# Bounds not working, does not even display markers when trying to add bounds

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps

The current code below does not even show markers, but when the bounds are removed, the markers start appearing. I dont know where I am going wrong. All I want to do is zoom the map to include all of the 3 markers. Currently it is zooming to 0,0 .
I do provide my api key, so that is not the problem.

Code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <style type="text/css">
      html { height: 100% }
      body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
      #map_canvas { height: 100% }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<key provided>&sensor=true">
    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function initialize() {
var markers = [
{ lat: 61.912113, lng: 61.912113 },{ lat: 62.912149, lng: 62.912144 },{ lat: 61.411123, lng: 61.411123 }];

        var mapOptions = {
center: new google.maps.LatLng(0,0),
          zoom: 8,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),
            mapOptions);

var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds ();
var LatLngList = array (new google.maps.LatLng (markers[0].lat,markers[0].lng), new google.maps.LatLng (markers[1].lat,markers[1].lng), new google.maps.LatLng (markers[2].lat,markers[2].lng));
for (i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
var data = markers[i];

var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: "text"
  });
}
for (var i = 0; i < LatLngList.length; i++) {
  bounds.extend (LatLngList[i]);
}
map.fitBounds (bounds);
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an error when you create the array on this line (I've truncated the code for  readability):

```
var LatLngList = array (new google.maps.LatLng (markers[0].lat,markers[0].lng) );
```

Change it to:

```
var LatLngList = Array (new google.maps.LatLng (markers[0].lat,markers[0].lng) );
```

or

```
var LatLngList = [ new google.maps.LatLng (markers[0].lat,markers[0].lng) ];
```

Comment: Thanks ! I am new to javascript .. so got lost ..

Also could you help me with one more thing. If I add any var instead of "text" in title inside marker, it doesnt show up as a tooltip. Do you know a work around for this ?

Comment: That should work as long as your syntax is correct: `var titleText = "this is my title"; var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myLatlng, map: map, title: titleText });`

Comment: I have added dtime to markers .. 
var markers = [
{ lat: 61.912113, lng: 61.912113, dtime: 2013-02-05 13:27:55 } ...

and changed d javascript as follows... bt this dsnt show any output whatsoeva.. 

var dtime=data.dtime;
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.lng);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      map: map,
      title: dtime
  });

Thank you for your time @sunil-d

Comment: I'm not sure I follow that :) Check your browser's javascript console, it is likely it has an error message that will explain what is wrong. If you're still stuck, maybe create a new question w/the current code you're using.